# Linux ipv6 forwarding

Tags: iptables, ipv6

## Situation

I know how to do ipv4 forwarding, and expected ipv6 forwarding to work pretty much the same way. So I configured a VirtualBox host with the network address configured from my ISP. Right now, this is the network I have:

[image]
<sub>(source: [hjts.nl](http://tmp.hjts.nl/vboxnetwork.png))</sub>

## Question

I am able to ping all ipv6 addresses on the Debian router, but I cannot access addresses where Debian has to forward packets, e.g. from the Fedora client to eth0 on Debian.

## Configuration

The Debian server is configured to allow IPV6 forwarding:

```
root@6server:~# sysctl -p
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 2
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route = 1
```

Iptables should allow it as well..

```
root@6server:~# ip6tables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all      anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

And here is my address and route information:

```
root@6server:~# ip -6 addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:981:ec6a::aa:0/48 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fed6:b45c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:981:ec6a::ae:1/48 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe77:f6e8/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

root@6server~# ip -6 route show
2001:981:ec6a::aa:0/112 dev eth0  metric 1024 
2001:981:ec6a::ae:0/112 dev eth1  metric 1024 
2001:981:ec6a::be:0/112 dev eth1  metric 1024 
fe80::/64 dev eth1  proto kernel  metric 256 
fe80::/64 dev eth0  proto kernel  metric 256 
default via 2001:981:ec6a::2 dev eth0  metric 1024
```

On the Fedora client, this is the network route:

```
[root@localhost henk]# ip -6 route show
2001:981:ec6a::/48 dev enp0s3 proto kernel metric 256
fe80::/64 dev enp0s3 proto kernel metric 256
default via 2001:981:ec6a::ae:1 dev enp0s3 metric 1024
```

Comment: First thing to fix is the /112. IPv6 subnets should always be /64. Second carefully check the routing tables on every machine.

Comment: These are all the routing tables. Also, even if I configure just the ipv6 address, I have the same problem. I can ping between eth1 on Debian and the network interface on the Fedora client.

Comment: I see three machines listed here, but only two routing tables.

Comment: Enabling source routing ? Really ? Edit: Ah, home environment. Should move to SU.

Comment: You are right, I was focussing on the connection between Debian and Fedora, once that works, try to get the virtual host to play together. However, after changing it to /64 networks, I can ping eth0 on debian from fedora. Can you explain why this works instead of /112? I'd love to give you credit.

Comment: Xavier: it is a business environment, but if it is better suited on SU, I'm happy to have it moved to there. Or do I need to re-ask my question?

Comment: You have eth0 and eth1 configured with identical prefixes. That is not a correct configuration, when they are connected to separate segments. Also you have configured the link prefix as a /48, it should be /64. So you need to split your /48 into separate /64s for each segment and update routing tables accordingly.